# Is it possible to share a namespace across multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have the problem of circular dependencies and I can not change to class structure of the code I am working with ( Please don't suggest to change the class structure).

Now I could put all my code into one giant file, but that does not seem practical.

So is it possible that all my classes live in the same namespace, so that this would be possible:

File a.py:

```
from b import B
class A:
    def foo(self):
        B().bar()

    def bar(self):
        print("Hello, this is A")
```

File b.py:

```
from a import A
class B:
    def foo(self):
        A().bar()

    def bar(self):
        print("Hello, this is B.")
```

Without python exploding in on itself.

Comment: As a quick workaround, you may move import statements inside `foo` methods. Anyway, I guess it's a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but it's hard to tell due to simplification of example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding circular (cyclic) imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867676/avoiding-circular-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I would have to sprinkle those everywhere and also into the constructor of one class, which would lead to the same circular dependency again.

Comment: @EricRenouf It is not a duplicate, because the solution provided in that example does not work here. I will update my post to show why not.

Comment: *"I can not change to class structure of the code I am working with ( Please don't suggest to change the class structure)"* - please explain **why not**.

Comment: Did you try your example?  I believe that this particular code would work. -- if you import one of the files from the main module, which should be neither a.py nor b.py.  But other examples might not.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the file structure and/or class hierarchy, you could just move the import lines to a place where they don't end up importing each other.  They'd get executed many times, but if you don't mind the performance impact of that you could move the `import` lines to inside the `foo` definitions like

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        from b import B
        B().bar()
```

and the analog on the `B` side.

Probably refactoring is the better way to go, or use the qualified names as @RonaldOussoren shows in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have two modules that share the same namespace. What you can do in your example is to use `import a` instead of `from a import A` and then reference the class as `a.A` (and likewise for class B in the other module).